# Get mail id from google playstore while downloading apk

Tags: android, google-play, analytics

If someone downloads my android apk from google playstore, is there any way to capture/get their mail id, before launching my app even first time.

Reason: Some people have downloaded my app from google play store, but they would have not opened my app even once. so i need to capture them.

I can get email id using following code.

```
String emailList = "";
Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(ctx).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
    if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
        emailList += account.name;
    }
}
```

but i need a broadcast receiver to be triggered as soon as my app gets installed from google playstore. is it possible? is there any other way like google analytics,etc?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS

Answer (score 1):

Until a user has manually started your app, the app is in a stopped state, and will not receive broadcast messages (typically the one most developers care about is the BOOT_COMPLETED one).

So what you are trying to achieve is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get the play store account id before launching, because before launching your app is not started yet. But after the launching you can get the playstore store account attached with the device using the following code snippet

```
AccountManager.get(getActivity()).getAccountsByType("com.google")
```

See details for [Broadcast receiver of Package Installation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)

```
Broadcast Action: A new application package has been installed on the device. The data contains the name of the package. Note that the newly installed package does not receive this broadcast.
```